# One specific word in my URL triggers a 404 error

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-404, wamp, router

here's the thing. My .htaccess redirects all the URL to index.php.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]
```

In my index.php, I just put an `echo "test";` to try it. For every URL it works, everyone of them BUT, if I type "http://localhost/mysite/inventaire/", apache returns a 404 error and I don't understand why, it doesn't make any sense. I work on this project in an other computer and I never had this problem. The word "inventaire" seems to trigger this error and I can't understand why...

I tried to modify the http.conf as I saw on SO but it didn't help. I finally changed the word with "inventaires" in my app and it works like a charm, so strange...

Comment: Does `/mysite/inventaire/` map to a filesystem directory? Do you have any other `.htaccess` files along the filesystem path?

Comment: OK so I'm an idiot, I added two SQL files in my directory and didn't remember that, and one of them was called "inventaire.sql", so when I was trying to do "mysite/inventaire" it pointed on this SQL file...

Answer (score 1):

> I added two SQL files in my directory and didn't remember that, and one of them was called "inventaire.sql", so when I was trying to do "mysite/inventaire" it pointed on this SQL file...

That would imply you have MultiViews enabled, otherwise `inventaire` would not map to `inventaire.sql` (a physical file, which then gets blocked by the first rule). MultiViews should be disabled (it is by default).

To explicitly disable MultiViews, add the following to the top of the `.htaccess` file:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

Comment: Wouldn't MultiViews cause that file to get downloaded rather than show a 404 error?  I also wouldn't expect `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  -f` to test for things mapped by MultiViews, I thought it only checked the true file name.

Comment: Thanks for this explication, I'll add this to avoid this kind of problems in the future